# Do methods have to be created in a different java file?

Tags: java, file, methods

BIG NEWBIE HERE WITH JAVA**

I'm just now touching upon methods. I'm trying to understand them more but have some confusion.

Can methods be created in the same java file (main method) or does it have to be created in its own java and called by the main method?

Do they work if I create them outside of the main method scope?

Also is it best practice to keep both separate files?

Sorry if these questions are jumbled up. Methods confuse me so much.

Comment: Yes, methods can be created in same file.

Comment: If you're new, may I suggest a tip: **try it** :) you (probably) won't break anything, and you'll learn what you can and can't do best that way. Of course, you might not totally understand why it doesn't work, if it doesn't, but that's when you hit your favourite search engine/book/stack overflow for help.

Comment: I would recommend going over object oriented concepts at a generic level then dive into Java specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you create methods as class members.

You can place many classes in one java file, but usually it is one file for one class (it is the best practice).

So for example you can have couple methods in class where you have main method:

**HelloWorldApp.java**

```
class HelloWorldApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.

    yourMethod(); //you can use yourMethod here
  }

  private void yourMethod() {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Another example is where you can use method from different file (different class). You have to use object of this class then or name of this class if the method is static:

**ClassFromDifferentFile.java**

```
class ClassFromDifferentFile {
  // constructor
  ClassFromDifferentFile() {
  };

  public void methodFromClassFromDifferentFile() {
    //do something
  }

  public static void staticMethodFromClassFromDifferentFile() {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Then you can do this:

**HelloWorldApp.java**

```
 class HelloWorldApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.

    // create object of class
    ClassFromDifferentFile object = new ClassFromDifferentFile();
    // and use its method
    object.methodFromClassFromDifferentFile();

    // or use the static method witout creating object
    ClassFromDifferentFile.staticMethodFromClassFromDifferentFile();
  }
}
```

Read about classes and objects and you will understand better methods usage.

Answer (score 0):

in java you are write classes and in class's scope you can write any number 
of methods and create any number of variables and you can call this method from any other method's body not just "main method" , and you can't write method in other method body 
take this java file in

```
public class Box {
public static  void main(String [] args)
{
    prin();
}

public static void prin()
{
  //code
    System.out.println(getNumber());
}

private static int getNumber()
{
    return 10;
}
```

}